# Send dynamically div image to client mail

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-email

i am using html2canvas with barcode to make a dynamically image to specific div with the below function

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
html2canvas($('#printableArea'), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
     var img = canvas.toDataURL()
     window.open(img);
}
                });
            });
        });
```

The image opens into new winodw in base64
My problem is that i want to send the image to client mail for printing.
The image changes for each client accordingly and is specific

my php file is

```
<?php
include("auth.php");
//message
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$username =$_REQUEST['username'];
$surname =$_REQUEST['surname'];
$name= $_REQUEST['name'];
//mail body - image position, background, font color, font size...

$body = "Dear $surname  $name
Thank you for your Pre-registration for Global.
Please print the attached e-ticket with your personal barcode and bring it to the reception of the exhibition.
This barcode includes data about you which is required during registration. Having this barcode will considerably speed up the registration process
Organizing committee.\n".



$body = "Print e-ticket
(http://panosmoustis.netai.net/barcodeimage/E-ticket_2016.pdf) .\n".

$headers='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <http://panosmoustis.netai.net/>' . "\r\n";
$to = $_POST['mail'];
$subject = "EXPRESS REGISTRATION (Global)";
//mail function
$email = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if(!$email) { 
echo "Error sending email"; 
} else {
echo "Your email was sent successfully.";
}
?>
```

thank you

Comment: So what is the question? See [ask]

Comment: My problem is that i want to send the image to client mail for printing.

Comment: You should use PHPMailer, it makes attachments amazingly easy

Comment: @Zanderwar sure...but do you know if OP is able to even get it there...no. Specific problems have not been mentioned. That is the point of asking OP to provide a proper problem description.... not just a goal

Comment: That is a goal...not a problem related to code in achieving the goal. This isn't a tutorial service and questions need to define a **specifc code related** problem(s)

Comment: OP has his answer, move on

Answer (score 2):

You will have to send the image data to your PHP script. This can be done using Javascript's XMLHTTPRequest. Since it seems you are using jQuery, you can also do this with `$.ajax`.

You can send the raw base64 encoded string, and then decode that on the PHP side using `base64_decode`. Then you can just attach it to the e-mail, which is actually pretty difficult to implement. I would recommend using a library for this as there are many caveats to email attachments. SwiftMail or PHPMailer are both great.

NOTE: If using PHPMailer, you do not have to use `base64_decode`. PHPMailer has a method `AddStringAttachment`

Comment: PHPMailer has AddStringAttachment() that accepts base64

Comment: Even better! I wasn't familiar with that method. Updated to reflect your comment.

Comment: can you please provide the code ?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @aristeidhsP I'm sorry, but that is a lot to ask. We have pointed you in the right direction, along with documentation and the exact methods to call. Please give it an attempt at least.